# Ansible no module named paramiko

Tags: ansible, paramiko

I'm trying to run an ansible playbook (ansible 2.9.6) but I keep getting the follwing error :

```
    "msg": "paramiko is not installed: No module named 'paramiko'"
```

Even though I have paramiko installed on the machine ( #48~18.04.1-Ubuntu):

```
Python 2.7.17
paramiko (2.7.2)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the python interpreter:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
...
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0]
...
```

Use `ansible_python_interpreter` inventory variable  or the `interpreter_python` key in the `[defaults]` section of `ansible.cfg` to set the desired python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

For me was there another python version so first run `ansible --version` then check **python version** or **ansible python module location** or from logs when run `ansible -vvvv` then install it by using
 `sudo /usr/bin/python3.9 -m pip install paramiko`